# How to specify the SDK version used when installing a Python package on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, ldap

I'm trying to install python-ldap on Mac OS X 10.6, but I get [this error](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/424612/) because it's using 10.4u.sdk instead of 10.6.sdk. How can I specify the SDK version to be used? So far, I tried specifying the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET env variable to 10.6 and SDKROOT to /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk, but 10.4u.sdk was stil used. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When installing Python packages with C extension modules on Mac OS X, Python will automatically use the SDK and deployment target with which the interpreter was built.  Presumably you are using a 32-bit-only Python, perhaps from one of the python.org installers.  These Pythons are built using the 10.4u SDK for compatibility with older systems.  If you are using Xcode 3, the 10.4u SDK is not installed by default but you can run the Xcode 3 installer and select it.  If you are using Xcode 4, you're probably out of luck as it does not include the 10.4u SDK (or so I understand).  You can install a newer 64-bit/32-bit 10.6-only Python 2.7 from [python.org](http://python.org/download/) or you could use the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 (`/usr/bin/python2.6`).

Comment: The things is that I don't want 10.4u to be used, because the ldap.h file that comes with it doesn't contain a constant required by python-ldap. That constant is found only in the file that comes with 10.6.

Comment: the install indeed uses the Python from /Library/Frameworks. How would I make it use /usr/bin/python2.6, and would this entail any other changes?

Comment: Since you seem to be using `pip`, you should be able to do it by using the `-E` option to tell `pip` to use a different Python.  Something like this should work:  `pip -E /usr/bin/python2.6 install python-ldap`. You may need to precede it by `sudo`.  Otherwise, you can use the Apple-supplied `easy_install` for the system Python: `/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 -Z python-ldap`